# Make an AJAX call and downloading a document on the same click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I make a link that opens a document and make an AJAX call (to mark it as readed in the database) ?

My main problem is, on IE8, it must opens/downloads the document without opening a toolbar asking something like (according my client) "This website is trying to make you download this file, are you sure you want it ?". Apparently IE8 can be paranoïd if JS tries to open a file from a JS function. But if I put the file location in the link, this one is open and prevent the AJAX call to start.

Comment: Please provide code of what you've tried before.

Comment: Did you try `addEventListener('click', ...`?